# How to Compare Rows in same table with default row of each?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, where-clause

I have some question about selection has groups and each group WHERE by "Data1" if not exists WHERE by "NULL or Empty" else not show

Example:

```
Table T1         Table when data='00001'    Table when data='00002'    Table when data=''
Col1 Col2        Col1 Col2                  Col1 Col2                  Col1 Col2
A    00001       A    00001                 A    NULL                  A    NULL
A    NULL        B    00001                 B    00002                 B    NULL
B    00002       C    00001                 D    NULL                  D    NULL
B    00001       D    NULL                  E    00002                 E    NULL
B    NULL        E    NULL
C    00001
D    NULL
E    00002
E    NULL
```

My Idea is select table where by data and union with select table where Col2=null and Col1 not in first select

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col2='00001'
)
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table T2
WHERE T2.Col1 NOT IN (SELECT Col1 FROM T1) AND ISNULL(T2.Col2,'')=''
```

but if I have 30k records it's too slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Boolean logic & do aggregation :

```
SELECT col, MAX(col2) AS col2
FROM table t
WHERE (col = '00001' OR col IS NULL)
GROUP BY col;
```

For multi filter :

```
WHERE (col IN ('00001', '00002', '') OR col IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select
    col1,
    max(col2) col2
from mytable
where col2 = '00001' or col2 is null
group by col1
```